# Without our consent we are born.... where is this prayer?

Tags: prayer-book

I remember coming across a prayer that said something along the lines of "without our consent we are born, without our consent we will die" but I can't find it from googling. Can someone share where this prayer comes from and if it's typically in a siddur?

Comment: It’s from the Mishnah in Pirkei Avot 4:22, which is recited after Minchah on Shabbat